# Data gets overwritten in the redux-reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was trying to implement a page-by-page onboarding signup screen for which the first page collects users horoscopic sign and in the next page, it asks for name. The thing is the sign_id gets replaced by name. Please check the codes below

**action.js**

```
import * as types from './types';

export function addNewUserRequest(values) {
  console.log('action data', values);
  return {
    type: types.NEW_USER_REQ,
    values,
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import createReducer from '../lib/createReducer';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  values: [],
};

export const newUserReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  [types.NEW_USER_REQ](state, action) {
    console.table('reducer action test', state, action.values);
    return {
      ...state,
      values: action.values,
    };
  },
```

**createreducer.js**

```
export default function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action);
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  };
}
```

**Page1.js**

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onPress = (val) => {
    console.log('SELECTED SIGN', val);
    let value = {
      sign_id: val,
    };
 NavigationService.navigate('Login3');
    dispatch(newUserActions.addNewUserRequest(value));

  };
```

**Page2.js**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handlePress = () => {
    let value = {
      name: userName,
    };
    dispatch(newUserActions.addNewUserRequest(value));
    NavigationService.navigate('Login4');
  };
```

**Console**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change param in `addNewUserRequest` from `values` to `value` as only single value is passed. Then append `action.value` to `state.values`.

```js
export function addNewUserRequest(value) {
  console.log('action data', value);
  return {
    type: types.NEW_USER_REQ,
    value,
  };
}

export const newUserReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  [types.NEW_USER_REQ](state, action) {
    console.table('reducer action test', state, action.value);
    return {
      ...state,
      values: { ...state.values, ...action.value }
    };
  },
```

Comment: Looks like you want values to be an object. try `values: { ...state.values, ...action.value }`. Fixed in response.